# Getting An Error When trying to Calculate two columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

When I run my query I am getting a Precision Error. It is coming from my function after *

I tried changing the columns data type to an integer and to_number. it is a varchar.

```
SELECT * , (tableb.difference - tablea.order_bloomnet_msg_price) As Answer
From 
  (Select order_bloomnet_msg_type, order_bloomnet_msg_text, order_bloomnet_num,order_bloomnet_msg_price, order_bloomnet_id  
   FROM pos.order_bloomnet_msg 
   Where order_bloomnet_msg_type = 'ORDR'     
   Order By order_bloomnet_num) as TableA 
Inner Join 
  (Select Trunc(order_bloomnet_msg_sent) as Date,order_bloomnet_msg_username, order_bloomnet_msg_price as difference, order_bloomnet_num, order_bloomnet_id  
   FROM pos.order_bloomnet_msg     
   Where order_bloomnet_msg_type = 'PCHG'     
   Order By order_bloomnet_num) as TableB ON
      (TableA.order_bloomnet_num = TableB.order_bloomnet_num and
       TableA.order_bloomnet_id = TableB.order_bloomnet_ID ) 
Where order_bloomnet_msg_price is not Null and TableB.Date = '2019/01/03'
```

I want the final column to have the result of the TableB.difference and order_bloomnet_msg_price

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi @Thomas. We cannot really assist you because your query is large, complex and we have no idea about the data you are querying. Please edit your question and try to create a **minimal example** that can demonstrate the issue you are facing. We need a way to reproduce your situation to be able to offer any advice. Also, please include the full error message.

Comment: what happens if you change your select to (tableb.difference::float - tablea.order_bloomnet_msg_price::float) As Answer?

Comment: That actually works @JonScott, thank you. Because I am very new to sql, I get lost in how to ask the question sometimes. I now need to look at why that works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast your values to avoid the error

Like this

```
SELECT * , (tableb.difference::float - tablea.order_bloomnet_msg_price::float) As Answer
From 
  (Select order_bloomnet_msg_type, order_bloomnet_msg_text, order_bloomnet_num,order_bloomnet_msg_price, order_bloomnet_id  
   FROM pos.order_bloomnet_msg 
   Where order_bloomnet_msg_type = 'ORDR'     
   Order By order_bloomnet_num) as TableA 
Inner Join 
  (Select Trunc(order_bloomnet_msg_sent) as Date,order_bloomnet_msg_username, order_bloomnet_msg_price as difference, order_bloomnet_num, order_bloomnet_id  
   FROM pos.order_bloomnet_msg     
   Where order_bloomnet_msg_type = 'PCHG'     
   Order By order_bloomnet_num) as TableB ON
      (TableA.order_bloomnet_num = TableB.order_bloomnet_num and
       TableA.order_bloomnet_id = TableB.order_bloomnet_ID ) 
Where order_bloomnet_msg_price is not Null and TableB.Date = '2019/01/03'
```